# ListView: reset the content while scrolling causes an exception

Tags: android, exception, listview

I'm having this bug in my application: it's a ListView, with a long list of stuff. I have a refresh button that when clicked, will empty the list to refill it with new results.

If I click the refresh button while scrolling is still active (because of the "momentum" of the scroll), I get an Exception. I understand why, the scroll is trying to access items that are no longer there. But I can't find a fix.

I tried stopping the scroll but I don't find a way to do it, I tried to reset to the top of the list before resetting it but I still get a crash. How can I fix it? Surely, that's a common use case, I believe someone already had this issue before?

edit: exception is IndexOutOfBoundsException: invalid index 20, size is 0

Comment: What, specifically, is the exception?

Comment: You probably do not notify your adapter that data has changed. After you cleared your data (presumably a Java List) notify your adapter via mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: That's correct, I forgot to call notifyDataSetChanged()! It's fixed now, thank you.

Comment: @erwan You're welcome. I put it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably do not notify your adapter that data has changed. After you cleared your data (presumably a Java List) notify your adapter via mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()